# Schema.org type for mobile carrier support

Tags: schema.org, forms, customer-service, chat

I have a page which is online chat support for users for a mobile carrier. I wanted to put Schema.org for this page, but was not sure what type of schema does this support page will have.

Need to understand what should be the schema for mobile carrier support feature and why?

This page would be a form with approx 4-5 fields, the data submitted will be loading the chat HTML code in an HTML element, so basically my page will be a, sort of, login for chat to collect data from user for chat agent on other side. Hence I need only form to be crawled.

Comment: There is no reason to try to find some random schema to apply to a page.   There is no search engine ranking benefit or usability benefit for checking the box of "supports schema".   The reason to use schema is that somebody will be consuming the data and doing something useful with it.   If you have to ask which schema to use, then you obviously don't know that somebody wants to use it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, with due respect, don't be judgmental just because you are a Moderator, By the way, You are wrong by concluding that there is nothing which can be used, as written in the question, this form will help user to connect with agents, and hence this is relevant, I have looked into the schema.org, and i didn't find any thing relevant to the business, This was first time I am doing the schema, and hence cannot understand the thought process of how to chose one.

Comment: I'm judgmental because we get these "what schema should I use" questions often.   I'm sick of them because they shouldn't be asked.   I have yet to figure out why people are searching for some type of schema to apply.   It is putting the cart before the horse.   The correct way of going about it is knowing what benefit you want and then applying the schema that supports that.  I get the feeling that there are SEO guides that say "use schema!" but don't say what it should be used for or how to go about it.

Comment: Google is the only entity that I know of that consumes microdata markup on lots of websites.   They have a list of ways they enhance search results based on it here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery  If it isn't in that list, there likely isn't any benefit of marking up your pages.

Comment: Cool, first thing, nobody would know that you are frustrated of such questions, but if you would have read my question patiently, you would have understood, that I know what my page is doing, I know what the page will target to but also I want to know How to understand, how to think towards finding the Schema. U just did answered that "The correct way of going about it is knowing what benefit you want and then applying the schema that supports that." here, there was no need and this is not the place to puke in the frustration, spread knowledge, do not disrespect of noobs, Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding disrespectful.   I try to be helpful even when I'm judgmental.

Comment: No Problem, Sir, I am just a beginner to begin with SEO, Experts like you are actually the mentors to spread the word around. If you start getting frustrated because of silly questions, how would that work? Ofcourse there must not be the "What" and "How" questions everytime and for same thing, but you have the authority to tag the duplicate question.. Nobody can sense your perceptions.. Thanks for your help on that Google Developer link, I am referring to it now

Comment: I can relate to Stephen. I begin to think this schema markup thing is only to make the appearance of your website in search results a bit fancier but only in google. Since there are multiple search engines out there and since people are only interested in what they specifically want, I find going for a schema rather useless and time consuming. On top of that, schemas can cause a user to download extra HTML c**p to their device before seeing anything which in the end results in more bandwidth usage and possibly a higher internet bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the **[`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint) type** to represent the support chat.

For the [`contactType`](http://schema.org/contactType) property, Schema.org doesn’t define any values. Google, for their [Corporate Contacts feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts), recognizes a few strings, but their feature seems to be for telephone numbers, not chat. Among those values, the following might apply in your case:

- `customer support`
- `technical support`
- `billing support`

---

If you want to provide structured data about the actual forms (the form for initiating the chat and the form for chatting), sub-types of the **[`Action`](http://schema.org/Action) type** apply.

For example, [`CommunicateAction`](http://schema.org/CommunicateAction) might be used for the chat. Its [`recipient`](http://schema.org/recipient) property could take the `ContactPoint` item as value.

But if you want to go into more detail (e.g., to allow user agents to make use of the chat), have a look at the [Hydra vocabulary](https://www.hydra-cg.com/) (they [were involved](http://blog.schema.org/2014/04/announcing-schemaorg-actions.html) in the design of Schema.org’s `Action` types)

Comment: Excellent, this looks like a direction to move ahead, thank you so much @unor